# Is it possible to send CodeBuild CloudWatch logs to slack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, slack, aws-codebuild, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

How can we send CloudWatch logs of a CodeBuild project to Slack after all phases have been completed?

I have found there are ways to send the status of phases to Slack. Is there some similar functions for sending the logs?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "real-time"?

Comment: @jimmone I have edited the question to reflect what I require. Like, sending the cloudwatch logs of the codebuild project to Slack, once all phases have been completed.

Answer (score 1):

CodeBuild sends logs to either CloudWatch or S3 depending on your configuration. After your build has completed you can trigger a Lambda function which fetches the logs from S3 or CloudWatch and sends them to Slack. The trigger cloud be EventBridge event or maybe S3 event depending on whether CodeBuild sends all the logs in a single file after the whole build is completed.

Some links to help you get going:

https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-build-notifications.html#sample-build-notifications-ref

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-codebuild-project-logsconfig.html